# Invertible matrix subtracted by permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutation-matrices

*Sorry for the vague title, but I do not know how to describe the question briefly. If any improvements are possible please edit.*

> Given an arbitrary invertible matrix $A$ whose entries contains only $0$ and $1$, can we always find a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A-P$ also has non-negative entries?
> Equivalently, can we show that there always exists a permutation $\sigma$ such that $A_{i,\sigma(i)}$ are all nonzero?

When the number of $1$s exceeding $n$ is not so much, simple pigeon-hole argument can prove the case. However general cases seem to be too complecated to me. (Or the question is stupid and pigeon-hole can indeed do the job.)

There are similar posts on the site like

[Characterizing sums of permutation matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583874)

but I am not familiar with the methods applied there so I failed to adapt them.

> *Bonus*: Is the statement true for arbitrary matrices with nonnegative *integral* entries?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. The simplest approach is to use the determinant. Here's a proof by contrapositive.

Suppose that no such permutation exists. That is, for every permutation $\sigma$, $A_{i,\sigma(i)} = 0$ for at least one value of $i$. It follows that $\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i,\sigma(i)} = 0$ for every permutation $\sigma$. Thus, with the [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants), we find that
$$
\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i,\sigma(i)} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot 0 = 0.
$$
Thus, $A$ has determinant $0$ and is therefore not invertible.

The conclusion follows.

Regarding your "bonus" question, the same approach works for matrices with non-negative integer entries.